# SSH into a remote server; but my organization has blocked port 22

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, tunneling

I am using RedHat OpenShift server to deploy my WebApps.

To access the contents of my application I have to SSH into their server, e.g.:

```
ssh 56555ff90abcdefbf6e000077@appname.rhcloud.com
```

But the `ssh` fails, because of outgoing 22 port being blocked. Also, I don't have any public IP assigned system for port forwarding.

Is there any way to make the `ssh` work?

Comment: The proper thing to do is asking them access, maybe a VPN account.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Yeah, it's at least in part a social problem, not only technical.

Answer (score 13):

You ***must*** contact whoever is in charge of the network, and convince them that your access request is legitimate. Regardless of the sanity of the access restrictions, circumventing them will at the very least land you in hot water with your boss, and could even be taken as "hacking" and get you prosecuted.

Answer (score 10):

> **DISCLAIMER:** All the solutions on this answer, **can lead you to be fired for violating your organization security policy.** If there is a
>   Network Administrator that is constantly checking for abnormal traffic
>   peaks and patterns, you could be caught. If you don't want to follow
>   the path of making a technical kludge to get the access, i suggest you
>   to follow [vonbrand's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253609/34720) and request the access in a legal
>   way.
>
> As the one that is asking shown at the comments it's intention to
>   avoid  security policies using affirmatives like "i have no root
>   access" and "this port is blocked at my company" at the comments, the same way it is
>   using a throwaway account, I took the liberty to remove technical
>   details that would facilitate the process of creating the "solutions"
>   from my answer. However, the idea remains cause that is the principle
>   of the [hacker way of think](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html#attitude), a skill that anyone working with IT
>   should have.

**Option 1:** Put ssh to listen on a different port.

**Option 2:** Redirect the traffic incoming from another port to tcp/22(ssh)

**Option 3:** Use [`shellinabox`](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox) to make a remote web terminal.AVOID USING HTTP. Use a certificate as explained at the [`shellinabox`](https://github.com/shellinabox/shellinabox/wiki/Shell-In-A-Box-manual) manpages, even if it is [self-signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate).

**Option 4(non-root solution):** Pay for a simple server at a cloud provider(one that costs 5-10US$ month) to have a ssh jumpbox.

Comment: Upvoted because shellinabox looks very handy!

Comment: I am not having root access for the host I am trying to log into. :(

Comment: You can set up a port forwarder in user land (no need for iptables), and no need for root permissions. But will not be able to bind to low number ports (<1024) without capability CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE. If you have this capability then listen on port 80. All web based computers, these days, can access port 80.

Comment: I deleted my comment because this question is OLD, and the user wont come back. Obviously I would fire someone circumventing security policies and opening new security holes. There is no need for constantly checking, either syslogs from system or firewalls, or even a netflow server. Or at worst, it will become *very visible* when worms find out the ssh tunnel and start hammering you with ssh requests.

Comment: Relax. I was adding more stuff to the technical part, and even giving the advice to this poor guy about the legal stuff involved. I work with network and security too, and i would not think twice on calling my boss to get someone like the question OP fired ;). Just editing my answer in chunks

Comment: @nwildner no problem here ;) I did have security incidents and debugged them post-mortem with syslogs and a local netflow server. No need to be always on the lookout.

Comment: Yeah. and i've noticed that I gave this answer years ago, and forgot to tell the basics about legal stuff. Today, I got an Upvote and felt guilty about it so, mistakes we make and try to fix during our short lifetime on this planet :)

Comment: @nwildner It happens! the only ones who do not make mistakes are the ones doing nothing.

Comment: The user used a throwaway account and wont come back. To make this thread on-topic, would it be kosher removing references of circumventing internal security policies from the question?

Comment: I think the question is OK as it is.  One that is asking gave info about doing illicit things at the comments of some answers(i have no root access, ports are blocked...) not at the question. If you ignore those comments, seems that OP is only a "newby" on using this remote access technology so, would not be an off-topic on my opinion. This question hits that gray area where it is hard to discuss about.

Answer (score 5):

I like to use [sslh](http://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh.shtml) for this. It exploits the fact that different protocols start a connection differently. If it detects SSH, it forwards the connection to sshd and if it detects HTTPS it forwards the connection to httpd.

This allows you to have e.g. nginx/apache and ssh listening on the same port (usually 443).

Comment: That would be a perfect solution.

But I do not have sudo access in Openshift server.
Thereby I wont be able to install sslh.

Comment: In that case I suggest you look into `ProxyCommand`. E.g. `ssh -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -W %h:%p -p 443 jumphostuser@jumphost' finaluser@finalhost`

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to access the container in OpenShift is the oc cli tool.

you can use oc command line tool to access the shell. eventually, if you "need" to use your ssh client, you can forward the port with

```
oc port-forward <podname> 22:22
```

otw you can just use

```
oc rsh <podname>
```

to access with a remote shell

for more info 
https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure that the ssh server is set to use port 22? It is the standard configuration but can be changed. If this is the case and the new port is e.g. 123 try

```
ssh -p 123 56555ff90abcdefbf6e000077@appname.rhcloud.com
```

Comment: yes ssh server is set to port 22.
I cant change sshd file, because be insufficient privileges..